# Comments section for my application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook-comments, disqus

I want to add a simple comments section data of which I don't store. Just like [Facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) or [Disqus](https://disqus.com/).

I tried making a static HTML of the code that I got from these, storing it somewhere and loading that URL from a WebView in my react native app.

This platforms require login, it works in WebView mostly OK. I have to redirect to the first page after user authenticates. But login information is not stored, and user has to login every time she re-opens the application.

Is there a way to overcome this issue, or am I trying something impractical?

Comment: Whether or not this would work (opening a webview in your app with the user's cookies) will depend on the platform. Did you test it on iOS or Android?

Comment: Android. I tried on Genymotion to be more specific.